# How to get the cell content of DatagridTemplateColumn in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn whose header basically consists of StackPanel which contains a Button and TextBlock. I would want to access the Cell content or DataGridCell when the datagridrow is loaded.

My one of the datagridcolumn looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"  Click="HeaderButtonClick">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0.5" 
                                          Data="M3.875,0 L5.125,0 5.125,3.875 9,3.875 9,5.125 5.125,5.125 5.125,9 3.875,9 3.875,5.125 0,5.125 0,3.875 3.875,3.875 3.875,0 z" />
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                            <TextBlock Text="Fund" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fund}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

and the datagrid_loadingrow event looks like

```
    var dg = sender as DataGrid;
    if (dg != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in dg.Columns)
        {
            DataGridCell cell1 = item.GetCellContent(row) as DataGridCell;
         }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Add code if you want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is WPF, not WindowsForms. When using WPF, we data bind to UI control properties, rather than attempting to programmatically set these values. When data binding, you already have access to the data in your code behind/view model, so there really is no need to attempt to access it from the UI controls.

If you look at the [`DataGridTemplateColumn` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see this example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--DataTemplate for Published Date column defined in Grid.Resources.  PublishDate is a property on the ItemsSource of type DateTime -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Width="20" Height="30">
                <Border Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, StringFormat={}{0:MMM}}" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PublishDate, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy}}" FontSize="8" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!--DataTemplate for the Published Date column when in edit mode. -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditingDateTemplate">
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding PublishDate}"  />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--Custom column that shows the published date-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Publish Date" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingDateTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Notice the `Binding`s... for example, we can see this:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding PublishDate}"  />
```

This value can be accessed directly from the `PublishDate` property of the data bound object, rather than from the `DataGrid`:

```
DateTime publishDate = DataBoundCollection.ElementAt(relevantRowIndex).PublishDate;
```

You can find out more about data binding from the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Well I am creating a custom DataGrid in which I want to use it across my application, I would also want a special functionality of expanding and collapsing the rows.

Comment: That would not stop you from using data binding.

Comment: I would want to format the data at the row level, anyways I found the issue, I was checking all this data in Loading Event, while I now checked the data against datagridloaded event, I got the cell info. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is answer.How you would access template column content using code.If you want to access  any type of **Control** content e.g **Button** content ,**TextBlock** content etc.Then you create load event for those  **Controls**.Then go to load event code.In load event you would be access **Content** of those **Controls**.
I am going to access the **Button** child of **Stack Panel**.
So follow this code.
**Xaml:**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"  Click="HeaderButtonClick">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Path Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0.5" 
                                      Data="M3.875,0 L5.125,0 5.125,3.875 9,3.875 9,5.125 5.125,5.125 5.125,9 3.875,9 3.875,5.125 0,5.125 0,3.875 3.875,3.875 3.875,0 z" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="Fund" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fund}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Code Behind **.cs**

```
  private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel stack = sender as StackPanel;
        Button button = stack.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault();
        button.Content = "Change Content";

    }
```

In my situation I want to access  button in **Template Column**.I used this code
**XAML**

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="deleteDG" Header="Delete"  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Uid="deletetemp" >
                        <Button Click="deleteBtn_Click" Loaded="Button_Loaded"   Width="95" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="White" Content="Delete"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Code Behind **.cs**

```
   private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        button.Content = "Change COntent";
    }
```